# Entity Framework generates new column rather than using the mentioned foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using code-first approach to create database tables. When the migration happens it creates a new column name `ReceiverUserInfoId` in the database table `Complaints`. I have defined the foreign key relation as:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Complaint>()
        .HasOne(x => x.ReceiverUserInfo)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("ReceivingOfficer")
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired();
}
```

Model for `Complaint`. `ReceivingOfficer` column should linked to column name `Id` in database table `AspNetUsers`

```
public class Complaint
{
    [Key]
    public int? ComplaintID { get; set; }
    ...
    public string ReceivingOfficer { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual User ReceiverUserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the `User` model class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how the relationship looks like via SSMS:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried replicating your issue using the information you have provided and it works for me. Please double check the following points:

1. Are you sure that migration is being executed?
2. Are you importing `modelBuilder` from another file? If yes, are you sure that the file is being included in `OnModelCreating`

Comment: Thank you so much. I've managed to find the issue. It was point no. 2 that you mentioned.